# Extjs checkboxfield not rendering in Apache Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, extjs, textfield, xtype

We are using tomcat 6.0.36  and trying to do simple check box example but check boxes are not rendered rest everything working fine

All the text rendered properly,  i have created some pages with tabs, forms and grids all pages rendering except checkboxes in them.

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
  Ext.QuickTips.init();

var fsf = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    url:'save-form.php',
    frame:true,
    title: 'Simple Form with FieldSets',
    bodyStyle:'padding:5px 5px 0',
    width: 350,
    fieldDefaults: {
    msgTarget: 'side',
    labelWidth: 75
    },
    defaults: {
    anchor: '100%'
    },

    items: [{
    xtype:'fieldset',
    checkboxToggle:true,
    title: 'User Information',
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    collapsed: true,
    layout: 'anchor',
    defaults: {
        anchor: '100%'
    },
    items :[{
        fieldLabel: 'First Name',
        name: 'first',
        allowBlank:false
    },{
        fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
        name: 'last'
    },{
        fieldLabel: 'Company',
        name: 'company'
    }, {
        fieldLabel: 'Email',
        name: 'email',
        vtype:'email'
    }]
    },{
    xtype:'fieldset',
    title: 'Phone Number',
    collapsible: true,
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    layout: 'anchor',
    defaults: {
        anchor: '100%'
    },
    items :[{
        fieldLabel: 'Home',
        name: 'home',
        value: '(888) 555-1212'
    },{
        fieldLabel: 'Business',
        name: 'business'
    },{
        fieldLabel: 'Mobile',
        name: 'mobile'
    },{
        fieldLabel: 'Fax',
        name: 'fax'
    }]
    }],

    buttons: [{
    text: 'Save'
    },{
    text: 'Cancel'
    }],
    renderTo: 'build-dynaForm'
})
});
```

Thanks in advance

Raj

Comment: Which version of Ext Js and what browser it is?

Answer (score 0):

On your form no checkboxes. If you add them, they will be displayed:

```
    {
        fieldLabel: 'Checkbox',
        xtype: 'checkbox',
        name: 'name1'
    },{
        fieldLabel: 'Checkbox',
        xtype: 'checkbox',
        name: 'name2'
    },{
        fieldLabel: 'Checkbox',
        xtype: 'checkbox',
        name: 'name3'
    }
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/3FBzM/